# What is the correct way of declaring typedef enum array combination in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, enums, typedef

I have the following code:

```
typedef enum MyEnum{
A = 0,
B,
C,
D
} MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D};
```

VS 2008 gives me the error

> C2513: 'MyEnum []' : no variable declared before '='

What is the correct way of declaring an array directly from a `typedef enum`?

Comment: That's not possible in one declaration. You can either define a type or declare a variable, not both. How should the declaration given here be interpreted? You cannot have two equal identifiers in the same scope and namespace.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In C++, just remove the `typedef` and it would work fine.

In C also, removing `typedef` is suffcient.
However if you want to conveniently use `MyEnum` instead of `enum MyEnum` *elsewhere* then change a bit:

```
typedef enum {
...
} MyEnum;

MyEnum MyEnumArray[] = ...;
```

Comment: Did you mean: `MyEnum MyEnumArray[] = ...;`

Answer (score 6):

Remove the `typedef`statement:

```
enum MyEnum{
A = 0,
B,
C,
D
} MyEnumArray[] = {A, B, C, D};
```